# python socket chat server

Tags: python, sockets

After that I have connected to the server from input, how do I change my server in the chat?

I just updated the code with something that could work though it needs some more work, anyone?

```
def send(event=None):  # event is passed by binders.
    """Handles sending of messages."""
    global HOST
    global PORT
    global ADDR
    
    msg = my_msg.get()
    my_msg.set("")  # Clears input field.
    msg_list1 = msg.split()
    
    try:
        if msg_list1 [0] == "/connect":
        try: 
            HOST = msg_list1[1]
            PORT = int(msg_list1[2])
            ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
            client_socket.connect(ADDR)
            receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
            receive_thread.start()
            
        except TypeError:
            msg_list_tk.insert(tt.END, "Error: please write '/connect ADDR PORT' to connect to server\n")
            
    if msg_list1 [0] == "/connectnew":
            HOST = msg_list1[1]
            PORT = int(msg_list1[2])
            ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
            client_socket_2.connect(ADDR)
            receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
            receive_thread.start()
            except:
                msg_list_tk.insert(tt.END, "Error: please write '/connect ADDR PORT' to connect to server\n")
        elif msg == "/q":
            root.quit()
            client_socket.send(b"/q")
            
        elif msg == "/disconnect":
            client_socket.close()
            
        else:
            client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    except:
        msg_list_tk.insert(tt.END, "Wrong input\n")
```

Comment: What happens when you call `client_socket.connect` again with a new address (or use a second client)?

Comment: Do you mean what happens when I try to connect to a server after the first one in the current program?

Comment: Note: We don't understand what you are connecting to. But closing the current client_socket, or making a new one and calling `connect()` on it with a different server address is the answer to "how to change the server"

Comment: Right now I am basically connecting to my own computer if that would be in your interest(127.0.0.1 5005), how would that look like in the code(your suggestion)?

Comment: Well, do you want to stop the `receive_thread` and completely disconnect, or just have more than one server connection open and getting messages?

Comment: Well, I would prefer to disconnect and start a whole new chat in a new server then

Comment: Okay, then what is wrong with what you have for `"/disconnect"` then somehow get to `"/connect"` again?

Comment: Error: please write '/connect ADDR PORT' to connect to server\n"

Comment: its basically not doing anything as I try to connect again

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in variables. And better use `except exception as ex: print(ex)` to get more information about problem. Or maybe remove `try/except` to get even more indom - and put back `try/except` when you will have working code.

Answer (score 1):

A TCP socket is only usable for a single TCP connection.  If you want a second connection, you need to create a new socket and call `connect()` on that (i.e. you can't call `connect()` on your old socket a second time).

Comment: So it is basically a new client?

Comment: @sasasa It's a new socket. Clients are something you made up in your program, not something to do with sockets, so that's a question for yourself.

Comment: client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket_2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: Something like this? I might need some help:)